# String.format("%i",i) equivalent

Tags: arduino-ide, c++, string

How do I format an arduino `String` when I do **not want to print** it?
I know that one can use `printf()` or other methods to print a formated string and unfortunately that's all I find with google.
But that's explicitly not what I'm looking for, I want to assign the formated string to a variable instead.
There are `itoa`, etc. which I could use, but if there is a standard function to use like `String a=format("an integer: %i",myinteger);` I would really prefer this one.

Comment: The answers to the below question link might help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34775168/get-formatted-string-to-a-variable

Comment: see Rohan's link for sprintf. I recommend not to use Strings, but if you must: `String s(32); s += "an integer: "; s += myinteger;`